# How to create custom deserializer values of type 'java.math.BigInteger' and BigInteger []?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, jackson-databind

- Pojo

```java
@Data
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(using = DeserializeResultCalculateSumSequence.class)
public class ResultCalculateSumSequenceDto {

    private final BigInteger sumSequence;

    private final BigInteger [] sequenceRange;

    private final Boolean isCached;
}
```

I have tried to write

```java
public class DeserializeResultCalculateSumSequence
        extends StdDeserializer<ResultCalculateSumSequenceDto> {

    public DeserializeResultCalculateSumSequence() {
        this(null);
    }

    protected DeserializeResultCalculateSumSequence(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public ResultCalculateSumSequenceDto deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
                                                     DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JacksonException {

        JsonNode node = jsonParser
                .getCodec()
                .readTree(jsonParser);

        BigInteger sumSequence = node
                .get("sumSequence")
                .bigIntegerValue();

        BigInteger [] sequenceRange
        ....
                = node
                .withArray("sequenceRange")
                .binaryValue();

        boolean isCached = node
                .get("isCached")
                .asBoolean();

        return ResultCalculateSumSequenceDto
                .builder()
                .sumSequence(sumSequence)
                .sequenceRange(sequenceRange)
                .isCached(isCached)
                .build();
    }
}
```

But I do not know how to write a deserializer for **an array**.

Also I don't know if it will work at all. Maybe someone has experience and knows how to create such things. Please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

That's what worked in my case.

```java
public class DeserializeResultCalculateSumSequence
        extends StdDeserializer<ResultCalculateSumSequenceDto> {

    public DeserializeResultCalculateSumSequence() {
        this(null);
    }

    protected DeserializeResultCalculateSumSequence(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public ResultCalculateSumSequenceDto deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
                                                     DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JacksonException {

        JsonNode node = jsonParser
                .getCodec()
                .readTree(jsonParser);

        BigInteger sumSequence = node
                .get("sumSequence")
                .bigIntegerValue();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String sequenceRangeStr = node.get("sequenceRange").toString();
        BigInteger[] sequenceRange = mapper
                .readValue(sequenceRangeStr, BigInteger[].class);


        boolean isCached = node
                .get("isCached")
                .asBoolean();

        return ResultCalculateSumSequenceDto
                .builder()
                .sumSequence(sumSequence)
                .sequenceRange(sequenceRange)
                .isCached(isCached)
                .build();
    }
}
```